# JavaScript window.alert not working

Tags: javascript, input, quadratic

I recently began learning JavaScript and decided to create a program to factor quadratic functions. The program itself is longer, and takes three users inputs (secondnum,firstnum,thirdnum) representing a,b,c in the standard form ax^2+bx+c. The program functions normally until this block of code.

```
function discriminant(secondnum,firstnum,thirdnum) {
    var disc = Math.sqrt(Math.power(secondnum,2)-(4*firstnum*thirdnum));
    return disc;
}
ans1 = ((-1*secondnum) + disc)/(2*firstnum);
ans2 = ((-1*secondnum) - disc)/(2*firstnum);
window.alert(ans1);
window.alert(ans2);
```

My intention of this code is creating a function which solves for the discriminant, then uses the discriminant in the quadratic formula. I believe there is something incorrect about the discriminant function. Is this the proper way to use user input in the function?
I hope this question is not too specific.

Also if it matters here is an example of how I collect user input for (secondnum)

```
var secondnum = prompt ("enter b");
while (isNaN(secondnum) || secondnum == "") {
    var secondnum = prompt ("enter a different  b");
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you mean `Math.pow`?

Comment: @acbabis, I think the OP did.

Comment: i don't see where you are calling your discriminant function

Comment: Also, I think you need to `parseInt` the prompt.

Comment: Look at the Javascript console. It should show some error. Also, console.log is usually more informative then alert for debugging.

Comment: @Atutouato Its recommended, but its not strictly necessary in this case since both `isNaN` and `Math.pow` accept stringtegers.

Comment: @acbabis, ah, I see.  I never knew that before...  I guess you learn something every day here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure on the math, but syntactically I think you are trying to do something like this

```
function discriminant(secondnum,firstnum,thirdnum) {
     var disc = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(secondnum,2)-(4*firstnum*thirdnum));
     return disc;
}

ans1 = ((-1*secondnum) + discriminant(firstnum, secondnum, thirdnum))/(2*firstnum);
ans2 = ((-1*secondnum) - discriminant(firstnum, secondnum, thirdnum))/(2*firstnum);

window.alert(ans1);
window.alert(ans2);
```

which will at least get your alert boxes working provided `firstnum`, `secondnum` and `thirdnum` are declared before this block executes